# How to position system/OS alert windows/modals? e.g. in-app purchase

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I have a macos menubar app, and I have in-app purchases as part of it. The problem is my window(an NSPopover), is large enough that the system alert(which is screen centered), looks really out of place and jarring, and they semi overlap but in a visually unappealing way.

With Sign in with Apple, you can set a `presentationContextProvider` property that calls a `presentationAnchor` method you can return a window to, and it'll center the system alert on that window. I can't find anything like this available in the in-app purchases docs, and am wondering if there's something more general I can do to get the OS to center the alert over my window. I don't want to alter anything on the alert, merely the place where it's presented. Is this possible?

For example this is how I do it for Sign in with Apple:

```swift
class X: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
...
    func someFunc() {
        controller.presentationContextProvider = self
        controller.performRequests()
    }
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        NSApp.windows.first!
    }
}
```

But I'm aware there's nothing directly similar, but is there anything that achieves the same end results?